# How to use __local variables in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, vivado-hls

I'm trying to implement a convolution algorithm in OpenCL (using Vivado HLS). I'm trying to load part of the image into the local memory before executing the workgroup (for example, if the workgroup is 128*128 and the convolution filter is 5*5, I would load 132*132 pixels). How do I write the kernel so that the local memory is only loaded once when the workgroup starts?

Pseudocode:

```c
#define WKGRP_W 128
#define WKGRP_H 128

#define FILTER_SIZE 5

#define BUFFER_W WKGRP_W+FILTER_SIZE-1
#define BUFFER_H WKGRP_H+FILTER_SIZE-1


__kernel void  __attribute__ ((reqd_work_group_size(WKGRP_W, WKGRP_H, 1)))
convolve(
    const __global data_t* input,
    __global data_t* output,
    __constant data_t* filter_params
){
    __local data_t img_buffer[BUFFER_H][BUFFER_W];
    __local data_t output_buffer[WKGRP_H][WKGRP_W];

    /**
     * if (the workgroup is starting) {
     *     load data from input into img_buffer
     * }
     */

    filter(img_buffer, filter_params, get_local_id(0), get_local_id(1), output_buffer);

    /**
     * if (the workgroup is finished) {
     *     load data from output_buffer into output
     * }
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a single work-item per input pixel, you can have each thread load one pixel from global memory into local memory.

```
int x = get_local_id(0);
int y = get_local_id(1);
img_buffer[x][y] = input[...];
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

// filter here or whatever computation you need to perform
```

If your data is aligned, you could make that faster by casting to larger data types. See [this link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/vectorDataLoadandStoreFunctions.html) for more details.

Edit: have each thread grab 2 values until you reach your `132`. Of course, some work items might end up doing nothing in the process

```
int x = get_local_id(0);
int y = get_local_id(1);

if (2*x < 132 && 2*y < 132) {
    img_buffer[2*x][2*y] = input[...];
    img_buffer[2*x][2*y + 1] = input[...];
    img_buffer[2*x + 1][2*y] = input[...];
    img_buffer[2*x + 1][2*y + 1] = input[...];
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

// filter here...
```

Comment: The buffer is slightly bigger than the workgroup. For example, if the workgroup is 128*128, the buffer would be 132*132. Would it still be possible to load it this way?

Comment: @LimingXu sure it is, you can have a look at the updated answer. It's probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`async_work_group_copy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html) to perform a copy to local. It will return you an event object that you can wait on it immediately with [`wait_group_events`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/wait_group_events.html).

Or do some other processing in the meantime that does not need the data being copied. (ie: Computing some factors for the filter). To keep the work-group busy.

```
//Copy input from global to local
event_t global2local = async_work_group_copy(img_buffer, input, size, 0);
wait_group_events(1, &global2local);

//Copy the buffer from local to global
event_t local2global = async_work_group_copy(output_buffer, output, size2, 0);
wait_group_events(1, &local2global);
```